# Reducer phase not at all starting. It is always 'reducer=0%'

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have been waiting for ages to see the reducer phase start but it doesnt start. I have tried formatting the namenode but still the same issue. I face this problem wherever a reducer has to run. Can anyone help me in this regard.

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/training/Desktop/student_performs_CSV.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE stud_marks;
Copying data from file:/home/training/Desktop/student_performs_CSV.csv
Copying file: file:/home/training/Desktop/student_performs_CSV.csv
Loading data to table default.stud_marks
Deleted hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/stud_marks
OK
Time taken: 1.633 seconds
hive> select count(*) from stud_marks;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201211141618_0002, Tracking URL = http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201211141618_0002
Kill Command = /home/training/Installations/hadoop-1.0.3/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:9001 -kill job_201211141618_0002
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2012-11-14 16:48:29,822 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2012-11-14 16:48:42,270 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.39 sec
2012-11-14 16:48:43,349 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.39 sec
2012-11-14 16:48:44,429 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.39 sec
2012-11-14 16:48:45,507 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.39 sec
2012-11-14 16:48:46,580 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.39 sec

..
.
.
.
.
.
.
2012-11-14 16:56:44,394 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 54.9 sec
2012-11-14 16:56:45,417 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 54.9 sec
2012-11-14 16:56:46,449 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 54.9 sec
```

Comment: Do the logs say anything helpful?

Comment: I have seen something similar when the reducers are not able to fetch the intermediate data from the mappers. This happened when the reducers were not able to communicate to the mapper because of some network settings. Make sure that all the nodes are able to ping each other.

Comment: i have tried setting the
set hive.exec.reducers.max to 9999 as well but nothing helpful happened
ChrisGerken: No logs available for this I guess
@PraveenSripati: I tried to ping the nodes and there was no response. Finally, I tried to match the 'inet addr' which I got from  'ifconfig' with this and now it worked. Thanks for giving me the hint.

Comment: Can you try a different query, say a select query with a where clause and post what you get?

Comment: @MarkGrover
As i have mentioned in my previous comment, the problem is now resolved. I achieved this by modifying the ip in '/etc/hosts' to match the 'ifconfig' 'inet addr' parameter.

Comment: Hi @ghosts, could you be more specific on what you had to change in /etc/hosts? I have the same issue with hive on a local machine and my mac address, 127.0.0.1 and ::1 are already is /etc/hosts. Thanks!

Comment: @MadEchet: Is your issue resolved too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got resolved by modifying the ip in '/etc/hosts' to match the

> ifconfig > inet addr

parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying to LOAD data from local machine into a HIVE table. In HIVE, this operation doesn't initiate any reduce phase, loading the data happens in map phase and there'll be no operation to be performed in the reduce phase.

To look for some reduce tasks try some other HIVE queries with operations like 'group by'.